# Tkinter - widget with 'grid_remove' built in as part of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am doing some experimentation with tkinter and have run into a bit of trouble with grid_remove. I can use it fine with a simple button that links to a command that removes a specific widget, but I can't seem to get it to work when it is part of a class.

When I try and run this:

```
class Text(object):

def __init__(self, label_text, r, c):
    self.label_text = label_text
    self.r = r
    self.c = c
    self.label = Label(root, text = self.label_text).grid(row = self.r, column = self.c)

def hide(self):
    self.grid_remove()
def show(self):
    self.grid()
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'grid_remove'
```

I also want to have a button controlling the visibility of the widgets, so how should I specify a command for the button? At the moment I have:

```
button = Button(root, text = 'Hide', command = one.hide()).grid(row = 2)
```

Comment: There's no attribute `grid_remove` in `Text`, read the error.

Comment: @AndrewL. Well how would I use `grid_remove` to hide a widget that has been created with the `Text` class?

Comment: @NickB: call `grid_remove` on the widget you want to remove. You'll also need to read the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25092744/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for your help, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for others who have come across this problem, here's what I needed to change in order to get my script to work.

First of all, writing `.grid()` right after creating the `Label` was assigning the value of `grid` to `self.label` instead of assigning `Label` to it. The value of `grid` is a value of none so that was creating the first error. After fixing that part of the code it looks like:

```
self.label = Label(root, text = self.label_text)
self.label.grid(row = self.r, column = self.c)
```

The next problem was defining the `hide` and `show` functions. I was trying to `grid_remove` the whole `Text` class. However, the `Text` class comprises of many different things, one of which is a `Label`. I needed to specify to apply `grid_remove` to only the `Label` instead of the whole class. After fixing the definitions they look like this:

```
def hide(self):
    self.label.grid_remove()

def show(self):
    self.label.grid()
```

And the last error was the command in the buttons. I had written `command = one.hide()`. However, for some reason that is not known to me, I instead had to write only `command = one.hide` without the parentheses. After fixing that the buttons look like:

```
button = Button(root, text = 'Hide', command = one.hide).grid(row = 2)
```

So the reason my script wasn't working was not due to one simple error but a combination of all of these. I hope this will help someone else in the future!